How to bring back window which starts only once after new blender version is instaled and it offers you to load previous Blender version settings?
After installing new version of Blender, I accidentally clicked away, and didn't load all my settings.
Is there an easy way to start it again without reinstalling the whole Blender again?


Here is a comment by @Gorgious which is for a much older version, but it might still help: Import settings / shortcuts from an old version

This is a comment from a thread on CGCookie.com which might work and is probably similar to @Gorgious's post..

Yup. I don't think there is any other way than to tweak the appdata (on windows) folder to make Blender think it's the first time you launch the new version

@Gorgious Not sure how the poster managed to add the image of that initial splash screen if he hadn't been able to get back to it! :^))

@JohnEason I guess he copied it from somewhere ;) Looks a lot like this screenshot from the 00:24 timestamp of this tutorial: How to Transfer Settings & Add-ons from an Old to a New Version of Blender

@GordonBrinkmann He's just trying to confuse us! (Not difficult in my case!) :^)
